# Editing or moving site-packages in django

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-two-factor-auth

In django ive installed the django-two-factor-auth package through my virtual environment, and it is installed in /env/Lib/site-packages/.
What is best practice of editing such a package? If for example i want to edit the urls (or the views)?
Do i move or copy the packages from the env/ into my django project as an app?
My existing project setup is:

- /env/
- /project/
- /app1/
- /app2/

As im quite new to django, im looking for best practices before i start making my own judgements.

As my /env/ is not tracked by git, i cant imagine i should be editing the package directly within.
I tried copying the entire `django-two-factor-auth` package into my project, but im not sure how to register it correct in **settings.py** (im also wary of having a copy of the same library in both /env/ and /project/).